# resize jpg inside VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a jpg I'm trying to put in the header of all of the pages on a website, but it's too big.  I don't have any image editing software on this machine.  Does anyone know how to resize a jpg in Visual Studio 2008?  I don't want to crop it, just make it smaller.

Comment: If it's a one-time thing, get Paint.NET.  Free and nice enough for almost anything an amateur would want to do.

Comment: you could use an online image resizer http://www.shrinkpictures.com/ , im also a fan of Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just might have image editing software on your machine!

`MSPaint` will resize your jpgs for you.

Unfortunately, Visual Studio can't resize images.